# Invoke logout function when route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I logout user when the JWT accessToken expires?

Right now I am using `withRouter` as  a Higher order component(HOC) to check for route change, but it only works when the user clicks the back button of browser.

I want to check for route changes at every route change not just back button. for example, when the user clicks **back to home** link, I want to check if the token has expired and then remove token from local Storage.

**AuthVerify.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const parseJwt = (token) => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(atob(token.split(".")[1]));
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};

const AuthVerify = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  useEffect(() => {
    props.history.listen(() => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
      if (token) {
        const decodedJWT = parseJwt(token);

        if (decodedJWT.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
          console.log("expired");
          props.logOut();
        } else {
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default withRouter(AuthVerify);
```

**Part of App.js**

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import AuthVerify from "../src/utils/AuthVerify";

import "./App.css";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Signup from "../src/pages/Signup";
import Login from "../src/pages/Login";
import Test from "./pages/Test";

const logOut = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
  localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
      <AuthVerify logOut={logOut} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: test page with accessToken]

[image: after accessToken expired redirect to login page when route changes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an issue with your `AuthVerify`, it should be called when the location changes. From what I can tell though is that you are rendering the `AuthVerify` component ***outside*** the router rendering the routes that are changing. The `AuthVerify` component needs to be rendered within the router so it's working with the same routing context handling the changing routes.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
          <AuthVerify logOut={logOut} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

I suggest converting `AuthVerify` into a custom hook since it's not rendering content.

```
const useRouteListener = (cb) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(cb);
  }, [cb, history]);
}
```

Move the `Router` to wrap the `App` component and call the `useRouteListener` hook and pass your logout token handler. `checkToken` here is a callback that would check for the JWT expiration and conditionally invoke your logout procedure.

```
function App() {
  useRouteListener(checkToken);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/test" component={Test} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Signup} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit invoke-logout-function-when-route-changes]

Comment: Thanks it worked! can you please elaborate more on converting it to custom hook? specifically on "Move the Router to wrap the App component and call the useRouteListener hook and pass your logout token handler" part.

Comment: @GouravThakur Sure... the router just needs to be higher up in the React tree in order to provide the routing context to all `Link`, `Route`, `Switch`, and RRD hooks. If `App` is the component rendering the routing context then it can't also subscribe to the context. The converting it to a hook is more for simplifying the code. You could keep it as a component and render `null`, but what's the point when all you really want is for the `useEffect` hook to run once and set the history listener.

Answer (score 0):

lets make a use of useLocation hook of react-router-dom

```
//import the useLocation
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route,useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

let location = useLocation()

useEffect(()=>{
//do whatever want to perform, just make sure it is in parent component
logOut()
},[location])


const logOut = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
  localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Signup} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
      <AuthVerify logOut={logOut} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: This will logout user on every route change.

Comment: if you see my comment i mentioned you can do whatever you want to. if you want to authenticate before logging out just add logic in the useEffect